# Generating observations in univariate time series modeling

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

I was given this process of a univariate time series modeling ( autoregressive model).
From this process I want to generate 100 observations using a while loop.

```
import numpy as np 
np.random.seed(17)
T = 200
alpha1 = 0.8
alpha2 = 0.15
u = np.random.randn(T)
y = np.zeros (T)

for t in np.arange(2,200):
    y[t] = alpha1*y[t-1] + alpha2*y[t-2] + u[t]
    
y = y[100:]

# Write a while loop which generates 100 observations from AR(2) defined above
# This is my first try. However, it seems that I am initiating an infinite loop for some reason. Does anybody have a suggestion on how to generate 100 observations from the process described above?

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(17)
T = 200
alpha1 = 0.8
alpha2 = 0.15
u = np.random.randn(T)
y = np.zeros (T)
t = 2
while t <=102 :   
 y[t] = alpha1*y[t-1] + alpha2*y[t-2] + u[t]
    y = y[:]
    print(y)
```

Comment: as pointed out by @felipe whitaker below, the issue is not incrementing t in the loop. Btw, some existing packages like statsmodels support AR models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should end your `while` loop by incrementing your `t` variable, otherwise it will always be equal to 2. Therefore, your `while` loop will look like:

```py
# initialize y, alpha1y, alpha2y and u

t = 2
while t <= 102: # I prefer t < 103 (=102 + 1) for no reason at all
    y[t] = alpha1y[t-1] + alpha2y[t-2] + u[t]
    t += 1 # assuming you are moving one step at a time
```